# In Vue.js, when the enter key is pressed, add a <br> tag to the text output

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, appendchild

I need to add some basic text editor functionality to an app.
I have a textarea that when the user types something, the text is outputted in a paragraph. I am listening for spacebar and enter key presses on that textarea to trigger methods.
I want the text output to also have a line break when the enter key is pressed in the textarea but I get

> `this.textBody.appendChild` is not a function

This is what I'm trying:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    title: "",
    textBody: ""
  },
  methods: {
    logSpacebar: function(){
      console.log("spacebar pressed");
      //Fire corrector API?
    },
    logEnter: function(){
      console.log("pressed enter");
      var breakTag = document.createElement("br");
      this.textBody.appendChild(breakTag);
    }
  }
})
```

The corresponding html (partly):

```
<input type="text" v-model="title"/>
<textarea name="" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="textBody" v-on:keyup.space="logSpacebar" v-on:keyup.enter="logEnter"></textarea>
<h2>Title: {{title}}</h2>
<p>Text body: {{textBody}}</p>
```

Comment: Look into the `refs` attribute, it should give you what you need. [This might be a good start](https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/accessing-dom-refs) - Too busy to write up a proper answer.

Comment: Ok, even though I don't get the expected result as all of the <br> tags are added at the end (my bad), it does work. i suppose I needed to get the DOM element to use appendChild on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid manually updating the DOM yourself inside a Vue. Instead, use a computed property combined with `v-html`.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    textBody: "type some text\nwith returns interspersed\nin this textarea"
  },
  computed:{
    parsedBody(){
      return this.textBody.replace(/\n/g,"<br>")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="textBody" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
  <hr>
  <p v-html="parsedBody"></p>
</div>
```